# Creating dynamite Vue components in a loop

Tags: loops, components, vue.js

Recently, I have encounted a wire problem when creating Vue components in a loop.

```
  for(let i=0;i<testInfo.length;i++)
{
    $("#home").append("<lib_" + testInfo[i]['lib_id'] + "></lib_" + testInfo[i]['lib_id'] + ">");
    console.log(i);

    Vue.component('lib_' + testInfo[i]['lib_id'], {
        template: '#' + testInfo[i]['lib_id'],
        created: function () {
            this.count=i;
            this.libTitle=testInfo[i]['lib_title'];
            this.row=testInfo[i]['row'];
            this.imgUrl=testInfo[i]['img_url'];
            alert(i);
            this.itemUrl=testInfo[i]['item_url'];
            this.libNum=testInfo[i]['lib_num'];
            this.libNumMax=testInfo[i]['lib_num_max'];
        },
        data: function(){
            }
    });
}
new Vue({
    el: '#home'
});
```

The result of console.log(i) : 0 1 2 which is normal
However, the result of alert(i) : 0 2 2 is wired.

At first, I thought it's a problem related to creating closure in loop so I changed "var i" into "let i", but it doesn't work.

And then, I changed my code as following

```
for(let i=0;i<testInfo.length;i++)
{
    $("#home").append("<lib_" + testInfo[i]['lib_id'] + "></lib_" + testInfo[i]['lib_id'] + ">");
    console.log(i);

    Vue.component('lib_' + testInfo[i]['lib_id'], {
        template: '#' + testInfo[i]['lib_id'],
        created: function () {
            this.count=i;
            this.libTitle=testInfo[i]['lib_title'];
            this.row=testInfo[i]['row'];
            this.imgUrl=testInfo[i]['img_url'];
            alert(i);
            this.itemUrl=testInfo[i]['item_url'];
            this.libNum=testInfo[i]['lib_num'];
            this.libNumMax=testInfo[i]['lib_num_max'];     
        }(i),
        data: function(){
            }
    });
}  new Vue({
    el: '#home'
});
```

Now the alert(i) result is correct: 0 1 2

But the "this" keyword refere to the "window object" rather than the "new vue object".

This problem makes me crazy... Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the created function will be executed much later, when the component is actually created (not when it's registered, which is what you do in the for loop).

At this point, the for loop is/may be already finished, so i = 2 (I wrote may because of asynchronicity of DOM update etc. in Vue)

Why do you do this? The whole process smells like a big anti-pattern. Why can't you use one `lib`component and pass the data as props? why do you save all this data diretly on the Vue instance (`this.itemUrl= ...`) instead of the component's `data`?

It seems to me you try to use Vue without any of the useful features it proides for re-suable components...

That being said, If you want to "cache" the result of `i` to be available when `created` is actually run, you should add it as a `data` prop

```
data: function () {
  return {
    i: i
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I am a beginner of Vuejs. What I want to do is to connect different templates to different tags dynamitaly, according to the data from server. As you can see from my code, firstly, I create new tags (depending on data from server), and then I registe different templates to those tags. To be more specific, I want each row of database coresponds to a tag. And the template regist with that tag depends on the value of the row. Is it possible for me to do this with vuejs? If yes, what funcionality of vue will you suggest (or some tutorials)? Thank you.

Comment: are the templates (`'#' + testInfo[i]['lib_id']`) of a limited number, predefined in the page, or do you also define them dynamically from the server and there can be an unknown number of different types of templates?

I'm thinking about a solution involing Vue's `<partial>` element, but that requires to define the templates upfront.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. The templates are of a limited number ,predefined in the page. Your solution to return an object in data really woks ^^ .  But I've encounted another wired problem: when the type of `testInfo[i]['lib_id']` is `double`, which is defined in database, an error will occur saying that "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number". And then, i tried to convert `testInfo[i]['lib_id']` into a string and added it into `'lib_' + testInfo[i]['lib_id']`, but I still got the same error. If the type of `testInfo[i]['lib_id']` is `int`, everything works fine. Any help? Thank you